# Uncrustify space after opening c comment

Tags: uncrustify

I'm trying to find an option in Uncrustify that does nearly what `sp_cmt_cpp_start` does for C++ comments but for c.

Specifically, what I would like is to change this comment:

```
/*some comment*/
```

to this:

```
/* some comment */
```

Is there an option for this?